# How to turn on sensors (like gyroscope, accelerometer)

Tags: android, adb

All my sensors, gyroscope, accelerometer and everything like that were disabled.My phone is poco x3 pro, how  I can turn them back on?  The phone does not have root, but have TWRP, I tried rebooting and even resetting to factory settings, nothing helps

Comment: Try install a stock Firmware image and retry. BTW: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Android user questions belong to https://android.stackexchange.com